# how to resize the largerimage in to smaller one with height and with of 100dp and 150dp with out losing the qulaity of the image

Tags: android, android-layout

the logic which i used is as follows but it is still blurry

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromPath(int targetW, int targetH,
            String photopath, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {

        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inDither=true;
        options.inScaled=true;
        options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed=true;
        options.inPurgeable=true;
        options.inInputShareable=true;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photopath, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth,
                options.outHeight, dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photopath, options);

        return bitmap;

    }

public static int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight,
            int dstWidth, int dstHeight, ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float) srcWidth / (float) srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float) dstWidth / (float) dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            } else {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            }
        } else {
            final float srcAspect = (float) srcWidth / (float) srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float) dstWidth / (float) dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            } else {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            }
        }
    }
```

any body plz help me

Comment: you can use aspect ratio to crop you image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitmap's [createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) to create a scaled (down) image without losing quality.